# Javascript - WAV file data to byte array conversion issue - getting lot of noise

Tags: javascript, arrays, audio, wav

I have an API that returns a WAV file. In my Javascript I am trying to convert the raw data to a byte array. I am getting a lot of noise/static in the final audio.
Can someone please tell me how I can fix the byte array conversion (getByteArray method). Thank you!

```js
  var fileElem = document.getElementById('file-input');
  fileElem.addEventListener('change', readSingleFile, false);

  function readSingleFile(e) {
    var file = e.target.files[0];
    if (!file) {
      return;
    }
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      var contents = e.target.result;
      playAudio(contents);
    };
    reader.readAsText(file);
  }

  function playAudio(dataStr) {
    var array = getByteArray(dataStr);
    var isWAV = array[0] === 82 && array[1] === 73 && array[2] === 70 && array[3] === 70 &&
      array[8] === 87 && array[9] === 65 && array[10] === 86 && array[11] === 69;
    console.log("Is a valid WAV File? : " + isWAV);
    var message = document.getElementById('message');
    if (isWAV) {
      message.innerHTML = "";
      // Create blob from Uint8Array & Object URL.
      var blob = new Blob([array], {
        type: 'audio/wav'
      });
      var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

      // Get DOM elements.
      var audio = document.getElementById('audio');
      var source = document.getElementById('source');

      // Insert blob object URL into audio element & play.
      source.src = url;
      audio.load();
      audio.play();
    } else {
      message.innerHTML = "You selected a non WAV file!!!";
    }
  }

  function getByteArray(dataStr) {
    var array = new Uint8Array(dataStr.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < dataStr.length; i++) {
      array[i] = dataStr.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return array;
  }
```

```html
<h4>Select an WAV File</h4>
<h4><span id="message" style="color: red"></span></h4>
<input type="file" id="file-input" />
<hr/>
<audio controls="controls" id="audio">
  Your browser does not support the &lt;audio&gt; tag.
  <source id="source" src="" type="audio/wav" />
</audio>
```

Comment: Is this solved now? Also why `.readAsText(file);` instead of `.readAsBinary(file);`?

Comment: Thanks @VC.One FileReader.readAsBinaryString() solved this issue. In my original case where I was using a API response's body as a string was having this same issue. I resolved that by retrieving the file as a Blob by using responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob in my GET request.